# how can i give ratings of android application through RatingBar in Android

Tags: android

I made a screen with rating bar and i want to give the ratings of application that will reflect direct on the Android Market, please let me know if there is any way to do this.

Comment: Although, i highly doubt it, Check if there's an web API that allows you do this...

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible, you can't directly interact with the market and post a rating of your app. You can only open the rating-page of the market and let the user rate himself.

This can be done using a intent with the url `market://details?id=<packagename>`, for futher information see the [android help](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html#marketintent).

Comment: please let me know how can i open the rating page?

Comment: i am trying to open market url through intent by my application is getting crash, please help me how can i create intent with action view i m using Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

     intent.setData(Uri.parse("www.youtube.com"));

     startActivity(intent);

Comment: www.youtube.com is not a valid uri, you need a protocol like http

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the open-source [android market api](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-api/).  I don't believe it is an "official" means to adjust ratings, but this might provide you a starting point.